# Run an executable with a Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell-script, mplayer

I have `mplayer` installed and I want to create a simple shell script that runs in `bash` and executes `mplayer *` in the current directory. So, how to call upon `mplayer` in the shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mplayer` command in your script in the same way as you use it in terminal. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# some bash code here

cd /path/to/where/you/want/to/start/mplayer
mplayer *

# more bash code here
```

See also: [`man mplayer`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/mplayer.1.php).

Comment: Normally, this won't work, because in most distros out there, the current directory is not in $PATH. Youwant to use ./mplayer instead of mplayer

Comment: @BonsiScott Well, I specified: *in the same way as you use it in terminal*.

Comment: @BonsiScott Why on earth would `mplayer` be installed in the current directory? It's usually in the PATH. The question requests running `mplayer` with a certain directory current, not running an `mplayer` executable in a particular directory.